# How to make a batch file to run a python application

Tags: python, python-2.7, batch-file

I have a folder named app which consists of few py files.

```
Folder App
   - a.py
   - b.py
   - c.py
   - main.py
```

I have to run main.py file to run this application which is linked with other files.

My question is can i create a batch file to run this application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `main.py` you can import all the files which it requires.
**Python 3**

```
from .a import *
from .b import *
```

This will import everything in `a.py` and `b.py` in `main.py`

If you really want to make a batch script, you can just write following in a file with **.bat** extension, say `controller.bat`:

If `controller.bat` is in same directory:

```
python3 main.py
```

If `controller.bat` is in some different directory, then you will need to give full path to `main.py`, something like this:

```
python3 "D://mydrive/pythonCodes/apps/main.py"
```

Comment: yes i did import. My problem is how to create batch file for main.py so i can run my application with that bat file